# I need to filter data without missing information, it is character but I can't filter it

Tags: r, regex, filter, rvest

library(XML)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

presid <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_presidents_of_Peru") %>% # read the html page

```
 html_nodes("table") %>% # extract nodes which contain a table
  .[3] %>% # select the node which contains the relevant table
  html_table(header = NA,
             trim = T) # extract the table

t3 <- presid[[1]] # flatten data

t4 <-t3[unique(t3$N),] # eliminated duplicate
 
t5 <- subset(t4,!is.na(President))#
```

I need to read this table and filter the data in the best way that does not allow losing a lot of information when filtering the data.
The loss of rows is very important, it is reduced from 98 rows in t3, to 72 in t4 and to 63 in t5 when in reality I only need to reduce the information from 98 rows to 84 that can be filtered through column N

I have tried these formulas, but not result

```
strsplit (as.character (t3$N), split = "(? <= [a-zA-Z]) (? = [0-9])", perl = TRUE)
```

other

```
grep("[[:numeric:]]{2, }",N,value=T)
```

the rows of column N that I need to filter are those with the decimal point 0.5, 2.5, 6.5, 6.6, and others that have the terminal .5, in total there are 14 rows that I must remove.
my dataframe would be reduced from 98 to 84 rows.

I could filter by date but I have not found much material about it that can help me,

thanks

Comment: Which are the rows that you want to keep or which rows do you want to remove?

Comment: Thanks, the rows that I want to remove are c (1: 3, 7, 15:18, 22,27,41,51) I can do it manually, but I would like to know how to deal with this pattern of data from column N

Comment: I need to learn how to do it by reprex because I want to extend that logic to other html-table in internet. Thanks

Comment: What is the pattern that you want to remove from the data ?

Comment: A tibble: 98 x 10
   N     President  President  President  `Term of office`  `Term of office`  Title `Form of entry` `Vice President`
   <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>             <chr>             <chr> <chr>           <chr>           
 1 N     "Presiden~ "Presiden~ President  Start             End               Title Form of entry   "Vice President"
 2 0.5   "José de ~ "José de ~ José de S~ José de San Mart~ José de San Mart~ José~ José de San Ma~ "José de San Ma~
 3 0.5   ""         ""         José de S~ 3 August  ..is the the column N, the patron is 0.5, 2.5, in the row

Comment: Do you want to drop all the rows that have `.5` in them along with `'N` ?  So do you also want to drop row 4 ? So in that case final output would be 85 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data from the website has duplicate column names we can use `janitor::clean_names()` to have clean column names and then keep only those rows that have whole numbers in the `n` column.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_presidents_of_Peru") %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  .[3] %>% 
  html_table(header = NA,trim = T) %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  filter(grepl('^\\d+$', n)) -> result

result

# A tibble: 85 x 10
#   n     president president_2 president_3   term_of_office  term_of_office_2 title         
#   <chr> <chr>     <chr>       <chr>         <chr>           <chr>            <chr>         
# 1 1     ""        ""          José de la R… 28 February 18… 23 June 1823     President of …
# 2 2     ""        ""          José Bernard… 16 August 1823  18 November 1823 President of …
# 3 2     ""        ""          José Bernard… 18 November 18… 10 February 1824 Constitutiona…
# 4 3     ""        ""          José de La M… 10 June 1827    7 June 1829      Constitutiona…
# 5 4     ""        ""          Agustín Gama… 7 June 1829     19 December 1829 Antonio Gutié…
# 6 4     ""        ""          Agustín Gama… 1 September 18… 19 December 1829 Provisional P…
# 7 4     ""        ""          Agustín Gama… 19 December 18… 19 December 1833 Constitutiona…
# 8 5     ""        ""          Luis José de… 21 December 18… 21 December 1833 Provisional P…
# 9 6     ""        ""          Felipe Salav… 25 February 18… 7 February 1836  Supreme Head …
#10 7     ""        ""          Agustín Gama… 20 January 183… 15 August 1839   Provisional P…
# … with 75 more rows, and 3 more variables: form_of_entry <chr>, vice_president <chr>,
#   vice_president_2 <chr>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i need. Works for me